# In an nginx location block, what is the difference between "location /path" and "location ^~ /path"?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a WordPress multi-site network, and I'm trying to migrate it over to my new server one site at a time, so I have a reverse proxy on my nginx server pointing over to the old server for each subsite.

When I do:

```
location /oldsite1 {
   proxy_pass http://myoldip;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location /oldsite2 {
   proxy_pass http://myoldip;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I can access the front-end of the site at mydomain.com/oldsite1 and  mydomain.com/oldsite2, but when I go to mydomain.com/oldsite1/wp-admin, all the stylesheets and JS files return 404. Same for /oldsite2.

When I do

```
location ^~ /oldsite1 {
   proxy_pass http://myoldip;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location ^~ /oldsite2 {
   proxy_pass http://myoldip;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Everything SEEMS to work fine no problem, but I'm not sure what "^~" is actually doing to fix it, or if there is a reason I shouldn't be doing it this way.

The documentation states:

> If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.

I'm not sure how this behavior is different from simply having no modifier before the location path and why.

Comment: You do have other locations. Show full config

Comment: Locations like `location ~ \.css` will interfere with the first approach, but not the second approach. Look at the configuration as a whole.